# process.env.ATLAS_URI seems to be undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am following a MERN tutorial. `npx ts-node server.ts` gives the following error:

```
/home/jafar_isbarov/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:513
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
server.ts:16:18 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(uri: string, callback: (err: CallbackError) => void): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(uri: string, options?: ConnectOptions | undefined): Promise<typeof import("mongoose")>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

16 mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true});
                    ~~~


    at createTSError (/home/jafar_isbarov/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:513:12)
    at reportTSError (/home/jafar_isbarov/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:517:19)
    at getOutput (/home/jafar_isbarov/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:752:36)
    at Object.compile (/home/jafar_isbarov/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:968:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/jafar_isbarov/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1056:42)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/jafar_isbarov/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1059:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
backend
|-models
| |-exercise_model.ts
| |-user_model.ts
|-node_modules
|-routes
| |-exercises.ts
| |-users.ts
|-.env
|-package-lock.json
|-package.json
|-server.ts
```

My `.env` file:

```
ATLAS_URI=mongodb+srv://jafar_isbarov:cefer1999@cluster0.vzrcp.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

My `server.ts` file:

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv').config();


const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 5000;

app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json);

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;

mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully.")
})

const exerciseRouter = require('./routes/exercises');
const userRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/exercises', exerciseRouter);
app.use('/users', userRouter);

app.listen(port, () =>{
  console.log("Server is running.");
});
```

When I replace this:

```
const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
```

with the following:

```
if(process.env.ATLAS_URI){
  var uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
  }
```

I get this:

```
server.ts:18:18 - error TS2454: Variable 'uri' is used before being assigned.
```

Which, I believe, means that `process.env.ATLAS_URI` is undefined.

This problem does not come up in the tutorial. What could be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this error happens because you are defining `uri` variable inside an `if/else` block. You can't reach a variable that defined inside a block from outside. What should you do is defining `uri` outside of the block and assign the `process.env.ATLAS_URI` to `uri` variable inside the block.

So, it'll look like:

```
var uri; // Define outside
if(process.env.ATLAS_URI){
  uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI; // Assign inside the block
  }
```

Note: You can't create a null `const` variable. Because, variables defined with `const` cannot be reassigned